# What does "it does not meet our quality standards" mean?

Tags: support

I got this response when I tried asking [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44992/how-do-i-beat-level-8):

> #### How do I beat level #8 in Zero Gravity?
>
> The first 7 levels seemed quite trivial, but level 8 has me stumped. How can I beat it?

What does it mean precisely?

Comment: Oh, but now that it took me a while to get this question up, I don't have the question anymore.

Comment: Perhaps you could describe what you've attempted, and be more specific about what you're stuck on.

Comment: No, @Stephen that version of the question was allowed. It was a slightly earlier incarnation of the question where I didn't add "in Zero Gravity" to the question (but had the Zero Gravity tag). Adding "in zero gravity solved the problem.

Comment: Also, @Stephen I was stuck on level 8. I tried thinking about what to put in, but nothing else seemed valuable (given the nature of the game).

Comment: @McKay Either your body was too short, or the algorithm didn't like the `#8?` combination. I tried asking about an unlockable character named `???` in *Binding of Isaac* and got a similar problem. The algorithm probably thought we were abusing the use of symbols in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, they're not going to tell you, because then it could be circumvented too easily.

More exhaustive reading:

From: [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074/152101) (On Meta Stack Overflow)

> **Why am I getting this message?**
>
> All new questions are subjected to a "minimum quality" filter that
>   checks for characteristics of extremely poor questions. Your question
>   has been caught by the filter.
>
> **What can I do to get the system to accept my question?**
>
> Make sure your question has:
>
> - a clear title
> - a reasonable explanation of what your question is,
>     sharing your research on the matter
> - correct use of English and actual
>     sentences
>
> If your question is so brief that it could be looked up in a
>   dictionary or reference book/site trivially, it might not be a good
>   fit on our network. ([source: Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91072/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-cant-accept-this-question/91078#91078))(Requires 10k rep on MSO to view)
>
> **Can you be more specific?**
>
> Exact details about the algorithm are not being released by the team.
>
> > I am against being explicit here.... Our check takes into account
> >     tags, title and body. We are not going to give breakdown of what was
> >     wrong, that is spoon feeding. ([source: waffles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91253/make-the-sorry-we-cant-accept-this-question-message-more-helpful/91987#91987))(waffles is an SE dev)
> >
> > If we provide a "formula" then it's just another way for users to
> >     bypass the question quality filters. ([source: Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91253/make-the-sorry-we-cant-accept-this-question-message-more-helpful/91321#91321))
>
> **What are good resources on how to ask high-quality questions?**
>
> Fortunately, there are lots! See:
>
> - [The "how to ask" page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) (link is >for Meta SO, but it's basically the same page on every site)
> - [How to ask a smart question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question/18588#18588) (a [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) entry on MSO)
> - [What’s the best way to ask a question if English isn't your first language?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15308/whats-the-best-way-to-ask-a-question-if-english-isnt-your-first-language)
> - [Jon Skeet's *Writing the perfect question*](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) (will take a few minutes to read)
> - [Eric Raymond's *How To Ask Questions The Smart Way*](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html), (this gets cited a lot but it's fairly long)

Answer (score 2):

It means that your question doesn't meet automatically-enforced quality standards. What it means precisely, nobody knows, [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35256/sorry-posts-cant-contain-that-content-message-is-a-guessing-game-with-no-she). If you reproduced your question here, we could probably guess, but that's it.

The [error message's FAQ post on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards) might help you with getting your post through.